# how can I write (#include <libnotify/notify.h> ) without errors?

Tags: qt

I want to apply the simple notification example in the following link

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_standard_Maemo_5_notifications_in_Qt_applications

I followed the steps and added the 2 lines in .pro

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libnotify
```

but I have the following error when I write `#include <libnotify/notify.h>`

**error: libnotify/notify.h: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this missing in your .pro file?

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path_to/libnotify
```

where path_to is either absolute path like this or relative to directory where your .pro file resides.

Comment: @Marwa This error message simply means that compiler cannot find the file.. maybe your path is invalid. Try to copy the header somewhere near the .pro file.

Comment: I find that the folder i need to include (libnotify) in this path

C:\QtSDK\Maemo\4.6.2\sysroots\fremantle-arm-sysroot-20.2010.36-2-slim\usr\include\



this path contains also folder named "QtGui" and this folder used in the application without any errors 
--> #include <QtGui/QApplication>
HOWWWWWWWWWWWW ??

Comment: @Marva just include the whole path to libnotify folder...it must work

Comment: where?? in .pro ???
like this ---------->INCLUDEPATH += C:\QtSDK\Maemo\4.6.2\sysroots\fremantle-arm-sysroot-20.2010.36-2-slim\usr\include\libnotify

Comment: @Marwa only this: `INCLUDEPATH += C:\QtSDK\Maemo\4.6.2\sysroots\fremantle-arm-sysroot-20.2010.36-2-slim\usr\include`. If this will not work, try including absolute path: `#include "C:\QtSDK\Maemo\4.6.2\sysroots\fremantle-arm-sysroot-20.2010.36-2-slim\usr\include\libnotify\notify.h"`. And verify that the file really exists there!

Comment: I add it and this error is fixed but i have other errors because of the header files included in notify.h,I add the path for each header file causes an error.. and repeated many .. but there is 52 errors I can't them .. not related to header files 
Like this --> error: 'goffset' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you simply don't have libnotify installed.

Don't know what distro you're using, but something like `pacman -S libnotify`, `apt-get install libnotify`, etc. should work.